# Failed to convert a wmv file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

this is what the command i used

```
ffmpeg -i full.wmv -sameq -ab 128 -s 640x480 full.flv



  FFmpeg version SVN-r13582, Copyright (c) 2000-2008 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=${prefix}/lib --shlibdir=${prefix}/lib --bindir=${prefix}/bin --incdir=${prefix}/include/ffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-libfaad --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-libamr-nb --enable-libamr-wb --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libx264 --enable-liba52 --enable-libtheora --extra-cflags=-Wall -g -fPIC -DPIC --cc=ccache cc --enable-swscale --enable-libdc1394 --enable-nonfree --disable-mmx --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-libdirac --disable-decoder=libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --disable-altivec --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-vis
  libavutil version: 49.7.0
  libavcodec version: 51.58.0
  libavformat version: 52.16.0
  libavdevice version: 52.0.0
  libavfilter version: 0.0.0
  built on Oct  4 2010 18:36:29, gcc: 4.3.2
[wmv3 @ 0x6cbddaa79760]Reserved RES_SM=2 is forbidden

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, asf, from 'full.wmv':
  Duration: 00:31:59.95, start: 3.000000, bitrate: 1802 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: wmav2, 48000 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0.1: Video: wmv3, yuv420p, 448x352, 1600 kb/s, 25.00 tb(r)
WARNING: The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s
Output #0, flv, to 'full.flv':
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25.00 tb(c)
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, stereo, 0 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1
[wmv3 @ 0x6cbddaa79760]Reserved RES_SM=2 is forbidden
Error while opening codec for input stream #0.1
```

dont know whats the problem is but the other format files are succesfully converted with this command. The .wmv files failed...this is a windows media file is that the issue with this or my command is not the one I want to use for this

Please put your ideas please. 
thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question; it does not belong here.  Ask on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) instead.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may be using an encrypted WMV file.  FFMPEG doesn't support decoding of DRM encrypted WMV files.